# Express GraphQL must provide query string.

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, express, aws-lambda, graphql

I'm new to AWS lambda and GraphQL. I'm trying to deploy Express GraphQL app to AWS Lambda.

index.js file

```
  const awsServerlessExpress = require("aws-serverless-express");
  var express = require("express");
  var graphqlHTTP = require("express-graphql");
  var { buildSchema } = require("graphql");

  // Construct a schema, using GraphQL schema language
  var schema = buildSchema(`
    type Query {
         hello: String
        }
      `);

 // The root provides a resolver function for each API endpoint
 var root = {
  hello: () => {
    return "Hello world!";
  }
 };

 var app = express();
 app.use(
         "/",
         graphqlHTTP({
             schema: schema,
             rootValue: root,
             graphiql: true
           })
      );

   const server = awsServerlessExpress.createServer(app);

   exports.handler = (event, context) => 
        awsServerlessExpress.proxy(server, event, context);



 Expected Output:
```

[image]

But getting an error while executing AWS Lambda function in AWS Lambda console.

```
Current Output:
```

[image]

Comment: Hey, not a fix for your problem but maybe using [Apollo Server](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/v2/deployment/lambda.html) is a bit easier since you don't need all the express stuff.

Comment: Hi, I wanted to mount GraphQL server on '/' endpoint using express-GraphQL. @Herku

Comment: What is the context of this error? This result happens when your request does not contain a query (so neither in get `?query={...}` nor in post data `{ "query": "{...} }`). If you run the standard AWS lambda test without the necessary parameters you might get this response. Also I am not sure if the AWS lambda version is able to deliver the GraphiQL.

Comment: Hello @srinivas, Did you resolve this error?
I am facing the same error after deploying a lambda function to AWS

Answer (score 1):

Your server is just fine. I think the problem is your query. It is misformed somehow. Since you didn't include it, we really can't tell for sure. But you might get better results if your request has a

```
Content-Type: 'application/graphql'
```

or

```
Content-Type: 'application/json'
```

and you make the request body look like this:

```
{"query": "{hello}" }
```

Note the placement of the quotes; if this is JSON, it has to be formatted like JSON.

Comment: Hello @Rap,
I also tried with ```{"query": "{hello}" }``` in my local machine. It works perfectly in my local server. When I upload the same zip file for lambda function on AWS, I am facing an error that "Must provide query string". Can you please guide me what is exactly going on?